# Class instance that returns a function

Tags: javascript

I was just playing with JavaScript and creating constructors, and I came across this perplexing code.

```
var foo = function(){
   this.x = 1;
   return function(){
      return this.x;
   }
}
var x = new foo();
console.log(x);
```

I executed the following for this:

```
console.log(x); // The given output is expected for this line of code
console.log(x());
console.log(x()());
console.log(x()()());
```

All of the above gave me the same output as following:

```
function (){
   return this.x;
}
```

Can somebody explain what is happening in the above code.
I could not give a proper title for this question. Sorry about that.

**Note**: I'm aware of constructors in JS. And the above code was just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a long story short - it's not doing anything useful.

If a constructor returns an object, then the value produced by the `new` expression is that value rather than the constructed object. So instead of getting an instance of `foo`, you are getting a function that returns `this.x`.

It looks like this code is trying to produce a function that returns the `this.x` value of the created object, but that's not what it's doing. Since you are calling `x()` by itself, `this.x` is actually referring to the **global** `x` variable, so no matter how many times you call `x()()()`, it just returns itself.

If you used any variable name other than `x` and did not create an `x` variable (e.g. `y`), then `y()` would just return `undefined`, and `y()()` would produce a ReferenceError.

This would also fail much sooner in strict mode, becuase `this` inside the function would be referring to `undefined` when you tried to call it.

Comment: Urghh... I should have put a little more thought into it. Still thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is this:
x contains the result of calling foo().

foo() returns a function:

```
function(){
      return this.x;
}
```

the body of this function is written to the console

Comment: Then why calling `x()()()()()` will still return the function body?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev that fails with error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pbm2k37y/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny does it throw error when executed inside DevTools console? Because it does not for me.

Comment: Well I hope you got the answer now as mentioned by @JLRishe . The first call gives x the return value (in this case the function). Then since the context is not returned, calling x() executes in Window context-> the return function executes this.x. "this" here is the window. Hence window.x is returned, which is the first returned function.

y = 10;
var foo = function(){
   this.x = 1;
   return function(){
      return this.y;
   }
}
var x = new foo();
console.log(x());
This gives value of window.y ==> 10

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to the previous answer, that demonstrates it:

```
var x = 5;
var foo = function(){
   this.x = 1;
   return function(){
      return this.x;
   }
}
var b = new foo();
b() //--> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is all about function invocation context.

At runtime, the `this` referenced in `this.x = 1;` is bound to a different object than the `this` referenced in `return this.x;`

`x()` invokes the anonymous function returned by foo, in a global context.  For ECMAScript 3 (and earlier) environment, global context function invocation binds the global object to `this`, inside the invoked function.  Thus, `return this.x;` refers to `var x` you define on the global object.

In ECMAScript 5, `use strict;` statement can be placed in any function declaration to disable the binding of the global object in "this" way.

The anonymous, nested function can access "foo's" `this` in a closure:

```
var foo = function(){
   this.x = 1;
   var that = this;
   return function(){
      return that.x;
   }
}
var x = new foo();
console.log(x); // function(){ ...
x(); // 1
```